# Unable to view menu xml in Android Studio, getting exception in plugin Android Suppport

Tags: android, android-menu, androiddesignsupport

Whenever I open my xml layout mentioned below , Android studio displays an error message about Exception in plugin Android Support.

[image: XML file]

Error which I am getting

```
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.getRenderResult(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:602)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenViewBase.getResult(ScreenViewBase.java:109)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenView.getResult(ScreenView.java:30)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.menu.NavigationViewSceneView.getPreferredSize(NavigationViewSceneView.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.SceneView.getPreferredSize(SceneView.java:95)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.createSceneViewsForMenu(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:265)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.doCreateSceneView(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:234)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.createSceneView(SceneManager.java:73)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.<init>(SceneManager.java:66)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.<init>(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:157)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.NlDesignSurface.createSceneManager(NlDesignSurface.java:145)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.DesignSurface.setModel(DesignSurface.java:281)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.initNeleModelOnEventDispatchThread(NlEditorPanel.java:143)
    at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.lambda$null$4(NlEditorPanel.java:139)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.lambda$smartInvokeLater$7(DumbServiceImpl.java:366)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Deleted the line

```
tools:showIn="navigation_view"
```

now able to preview , but nothing to show on design tab

[image]

Comment: add your error to your question

Comment: I'm sorry I answered your question.

Comment: You are contributing to the community , not doing us a favour here Umang , your answer did not help me.

Comment: Why to downvote the question though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 tools:showIn="navigation_view"  //delete this line
```

Which crashes the layout preview.

try Rebuild project or Close project and restart android studio .

Or open another xml firstly successfully then open the stucked xml again.

Comment: Able to preview , no show in design tab , have edited my answer.